# Xamarin Forms with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform

I am new to Xamarin and have created a cross-platform project in Visual Studio 2017.

When I build that project, I am getting the below issue:

```
Severity: Error
Code: MSB4062
Description: The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlGTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\E6430\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.637273\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
Project: TestApp
File: C:\Users\E6430\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.637273\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets
Line: 84
```

My NuGet is also get coloured with yellow colour.

[image: Image of error message]

Comment: have you tried to restore nuget packages, by right clicking on solution?

Comment: yeah already tried  but it's not working

Comment: have tried to downgrade Xamarin.Forms package version?

Comment: That's the error you'll get when you have projects referencing different versions of Xamarin forms. Check your cs proj files and as MShah says downgrade the version to match, if necessary.

Comment: i have   downgrade Xamarin.Forms package version also but still i am facing Same issues

Comment: I have Attached the Image Also For refrence

Comment: I've edited your post quite heavily to try and make it a bit more readable, and also to include your screenshot inline to make it easier for people to see - hopefully I haven't significantly altered the meaning of your question, but please check and edit further if I've removed something important.

Comment: Thanks and it looks good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Unload project from the solution
2. Restart visual studio and open solution
3. Reload project
4. Rebuild

If persist:

1. Just run Visual studio as Administrator!

Ref: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106784/error-with-latest-nuget-v2-5-0-77-xamarin-forms-build-tasks-gettasksabi-task-could-not-be-loaded